# Add a class when div is x amount pixels of top of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have is to add a class to a div when it is, for example, 100 pixels of the top of the viewport. So not after scrolling 100px but when it is 100px below the top of the viewport. Can anybody help me with this?

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = jQuery('#v0');
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 2939) {
            header.addClass('fixed1');
 }

    else {
            header.removeClass('fixed1');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there  reason you're using the the full `jQuery` qualifier instead of using the shorthand `$`?

Comment: Does `fixed1` exist as a css class?

Comment: You can use Window.innerHeight to get the height of the viewport (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) and then compare it with your div's top position by using Element.getBoundingClientRect (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: Yes i'm using jQuery because my CMS requires that...

Comment: fixed1 does excist as a class, thats correct.

Comment: Hi Orkun, I'm a complete noob in writing code... Can you please correct my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly you want to achieve, but here's the code. If the header is more than 100px away from the top (which is not very usual because then there should be something on top of the header) of the window, then the new class is added to the header.

```
$(function() {  
  var $header = $('#v0');
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    if ($header.offset().top - $(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $header.addClass('blabla');
    } else {
      $header.removeClass('blabla');
    }
  });
});
```

UPDATE:
Depending on your feedback, this is the first solution that came up to my mind. I think that's the behavior you need. Hope that works for you:

```
$(function() {  
  var $header = $('header');
  var $video = $('#v0');
  var $videoContainer = $('.videoContainer');

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    // Here we check if video field touches the header, and add 'fixed' class
    if ((($header.offset().top + $header.height()) - $video.offset().top) >= 0) {
      $video.addClass('fixed')
    }
    // Since both video and header is fixed now I needed some other
    // element to check if we are again getting away from the header
    // (scrolling up again) That's why I added the $videoContainer element 
    // to be able to remove the 'fixed' class.
    if ($videoContainer.offset().top > ($header.offset().top + $header.height())) {
      $video.removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Updated code:
https://jsbin.com/foyoyus/6/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Hi Orkun, thank you for your code. But I think I'm not clear enough. If you go to this page: http://publivision.mooke.nl/page/1886/vormgeving/ and you scroll down than at a certain point you see a movie which plays on scroll. I want that part of the page to stop just under the header. The header has a height of 90px. If I use my original code it works fine on my screen but it's different on other screens. Hopefully I'm clear enough...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But it doesn't seem to work. Also your example isn't working here... I hope I'm not robbing you of your time. I also tried isScrolledintoView but than I don't know how to use removeClass.

Comment: I think it's my bad. The jsbin code should work now. Please keep in mind that in order to make the code work for you, it should be adapted to your html. Such as adding a video container div or if there's, using its own class name etc.